# what is the role of a UML actor?

Tags: uml, actor

In UML what does an actor do? Is the actor a role (i.e person) which can only initiate the use case ? or is an actor any person or system that interacts with a use case?

Answer (score 0):

An Actor can be a Person who takes part in the scenerio that we build with the use-cases. It can also be an organization that takes part in some activity or it may be an external system that plays a role in the use-case.

Answer (score 0):

An actor in the Unified Modeling Language (UML) "specifies a role played by a user or any other system that interacts with the subject."[1]

"An Actor models a type of role played by an entity that interacts with the subject (e.g., by exchanging signals and data), but which is external to the subject."[1]

"Actors may represent roles played by human users, external hardware, or other subjects. Note that an actor does not necessarily represent a specific physical entity but merely a particular facet (i.e., “role”) of some entity that is relevant to the specification of its associated use cases. Thus, a single physical instance may play the role of several different actors and, conversely, a given actor may be played by multiple different instances."[1]

UML 2 does not permit associations between Actors.[1][2] The use of generalization/specialization relationship between actors is useful in modeling overlapping behaviours between actors and does not violate this constraint since a generalization relation is not a type of association.[3]

Actors interact with use cases.

got from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_%28UML%29

Answer (score 0):

Actor can be both a person or a system the critical point here actor is outside of the boundary of the system.